# Show Today's date by default in Joomla default Datepicker using JHTML::Calendar

Tags: joomla, datepicker

I want to Show Today's date by default in Joomla default Datepicker using `JHTML::Calendar()`, I am calling this in the Mosets Tree extension:

```
<td>
  <?php
    echo JHTML::calendar('','revdate', 'date', '%Y-%m-%d',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',));
  ?>
</td>
```

but by default text box is blank but I need to have today's date by default.
Its working fine when using icon of calendar by choosing date.

I hope you understand me.

Reply Fast and Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<td>
  <?php
    echo JHTML::calendar(date("Y-m-d"),'revdate', 'date', '%Y-%m-%d',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',));
  ?>
</td>
```

You did everything right, set first parameter as you set date.

Hope its helps..

Comment: One more thing to ask, 
as i did you tell me above, but when i select the date from calendar, it is storing the current date to the database. it is not because of the above solution, but its storing today's value to the database, what could be the problem? i want to store the value users select from datepicker otherwise default today;s date...

Please help

Comment: when the user select any date it will change the text value right ? then you have to check the date adding section to the table make sure both date format are correct otherwise you have to do that.